# splitting a whitespace separated string, ignoring whitespace within single quotes

Tags: java, regex, tokenize, single-quotes

My Java input `String str = "aa 2 xx 'b cc dd e' -o se '4-5'"`

I want to output the tokens delimited by white space, except for the white space within single quotes.
So, the output should be:

```
aa
2
xx
'b cc dd e'
-o
se
'4-5'
```

I can do it by splitting the String on whitespace, and then coalescing a sequence of strings like 'b, cc, dd, e, to get back the 'b cc dd e', but I want a better way, possibly using some regular expression.

Comment: You really need a parser to handle this in the general case.  What would happen with a contraction word like `can't`?  Or, would those never appear?

Comment: they wont appear as per my usecase, the whole thing is a cmd line with very specific things in there. i checked some other posts with nice regexp's, but they have \" instead of the unescaped single quote that I have.

Comment: Try using an alternation and a negated character class to match your values `[^"'\s]+|'[^']+'` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NQwQnP/1)

Comment: the following worked in java: "\'(\\\'|[^\'])*?\'|[^ ]+"

Comment: the 3 consecutive \\\ are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by iterate string and using a boolean to detect the quotes.

try use this:

```
  public List<String> test(String a){
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean quotes = false;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(char c: a.toCharArray()){
        if(quotes){
            if('\'' == c) {
                quotes = false;
                if(!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    list.add(sb.toString());
                }
                sb = new StringBuilder();
            } else {
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }else {
            if (' ' == c) {
                if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    list.add(sb.toString());
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                }
            } else if ('\'' == c) {
                quotes = true;//entra na string do quote

            } else{
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }
    }

    if(!sb.toString().isEmpty()){
        list.add(sb.toString());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: yes, that one works, just stripped the single quotes though. let's see if a regexp style answer also comes.

Comment: Hi Labrat. I searched about regex and formal grammar. I think this string can be express by a Regular Grammar. Then we can find a regexp for it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar

Comment: the following worked in java: "\'(\\\'|[^\'])*?\'|[^ ]+"